# Enviar 2 objetos Json por $http em AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, json

Estou usando `C#`/`EF`/`Angular`, no meu *backend* tenho o seguinte método, que espera por 02 parâmetros:

```
public dynamic save(Entidades.CheckList json, Entidades.CheckList json1)
{
    master = new ClassMaster();
    Entidades.CheckList checkListModel = new Entidades.CheckList();
    CheckListDTO checkListDto = new CheckListDTO();          

    return checkListDto.save(checkListModel,  master.contexto);
}
```

no `controller` do angular, tenho esse método:

```
$scope.Salvar = function (json, json1) {
    $http.post("http://localhost:55959/CheckList/save", json, json1)
    .success(function (data) {
        if (data == "200") {
            alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso");
        } 
        else
            alert(data);
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        alert("Erro");
    });
};
```

na minha *view*, estou passando dessa forma:

```
<div class="md-card-content" style="display: none;">
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
        <label>CNPJ</label>
        <input id="cnpj1" class="md-input" type="text" required name="cli_cod" md-input="" ng-model="cliente.codigo">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
        <label>CNPJ</label>
        <input id="PBMS1" class="md-input" type="text" required name="cli_nov" md-input="" ng-model="cliente.novartis">                                           
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
        <label>CNPJ</label>
        <input id="User2" class="md-input" type="text" required name="user_cod" md-input="" ng-model="user.codigo">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
        <label>CNPJ</label>
        <input id="PBMS2" class="md-input" type="text" required name="user_nov" md-input="" ng-model="user.novartis">                                         
    </div>
</div>
<!--ng-click="salvarCliente(cliente)"-->
<div class="uk-clearfix uk-margin-large-top">
    <button class="md-btn md-btn-primary uk-float-right" type="submit" ng-click="Salvar(user,cliente)">Salvar</button>
</div>
```

O problema é que só é enviado para o *backend*, um dos `json`, não é enviado os dois, como faço para que o método da `controller` do `Angular` envie os dois `json`?

Fazendo debug do envio:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível enviar 2 objetos do modo como você está fazendo pois o serviço de `$http` espera que sejam enviados alguns parâmetros por padrão. Segundo a documentação do `Angular`, que você [pode ler mais aqui](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post), o método `POST` espera por esses parâmetros:

> post(url, data, [config]);

Ou seja, o segundo objeto enviado por você está sendo tratado como configuração. Mas existe um meio de contornar essa situação, basta você adicionar os 2 objetos dentro de 1 único objeto, porém depois você precisa fazer o tratamento. Exemplo:

```
var todosJson = [
    primeiro: json,
    segundo: json1
]

$http.post('http://localhost:55959/CheckList/save', todosJson)
```

Apenas lembre-se de fazer a separação ao receber os dados no servidor.

Comment: Obrigado Celsom, axei esse link aki: que resolveu minha vida, fica a dica ai para os colegas: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002924/how-to-send-string-over-angular-http-to-c-sharp-asp-net-backend)

Comment: @alessandremartins na verdade o link que você mostrou tem a mesma solução que eu apresentei. A diferença é que aqui eu estou colocando mais de uma array no mesmo objeto.

Comment: Entendi Celsom, obrigado pela ajuda amigo, vamos q vamos.

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço aos colegas pelas respostas. encontrei nesse post o que eu procurava a tempos: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002924/how-to-send-string-over-angular-http-to-c-sharp-asp-net-backend)

entao, o meu metodo do angular ficou assim:

```
$scope.Salvar = function (checklist) {      
    $http.post("http://localhost:55959/CheckList/save", { checklist: checklist, parametro1: "parametro1" })
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data == "200") {
                alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso");
            }
            else
                alert(data);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            alert("Erro");
        });

};
```

dessa forma, é possivel passar varios parametros, no meu exemplo ali, o meu primeiro parametro é um json, que no meu backend será convertido automaticamente para o tipo checkList, o segundo parametro é uma string. Isso abre muitas possibillidades.

Comment: isso é exatamente a mesma coisa coisa que eu publiquei na minha resposta, poŕém a minha solucao  é feita por etapas